# Sql Query show same output 6 time for single run

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to using sql count query and use some arithmetic operation on fetched result. After all this i print this result. I am getting correct answer but 6 time. I used core php as coding language.

```
 $qu="select (SELECT COUNT(P_no) FROM add_new_patient WHERE Branch='$br' and 
 Result='POSITIVE') as pos,(SELECT COUNT(P_no) FROM add_new_patient WHERE 
 Branch='$br') as tot,(SELECT COUNT(P_no) FROM add_new_patient WHERE 
 Branch='$br' and Result='NONE') as pen from add_new_patient ";
 $res2=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
 if($res2 && mysqli_num_rows($res2)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2))
             { 
                $r1=$row['pos'];
                $r2=$row['tot'];
                $r3=$row['pen'];
                $r4= $r2 - $r3; 
                $r5 =$r1 * 100;
                if($r4 == 0)
                    {
                        $r6 =0;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $r6 = $r5 / $r4;
                    }
                echo "<td>$r6</td></tr>";
            }
    }   


 Sql Schema :
 P_no  Branch   Result
 1     UDAIPUR  POSITIVE
 2     DELHI    POSITIVE
 3     PUNE     POSITIVE
 4     JAIPUR   NONE

Output is:
r1 = 3;
r2 = 4;
r3 = 1;
r4 = 4-1=3;
r5= 3 * 100= 300
r6 = 300 / 3 =100;
I am getting this 100 but 6 times for single run
```

Comment: can you add total php code

Comment: please post your sql schema

Comment: i can't add whole code because it has too much queries, i included this because only this part having problem.

Comment: I think you add 'limit 1' in your query your code should be work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo result after while loop dude.Hope it will help you.

```
 $qu="select (SELECT COUNT(P_no) FROM add_new_patient WHERE Branch='$br' and 
 Result='POSITIVE') as pos,(SELECT COUNT(P_no) FROM add_new_patient WHERE 
 Branch='$br') as tot,(SELECT COUNT(P_no) FROM add_new_patient WHERE 
 Branch='$br' and Result='NONE') as pen from add_new_patient ";
 $res2=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
 if($res2 && mysqli_num_rows($res2)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2))
             { 
                $r1=$row['pos'];
                $r2=$row['tot'];
                $r3=$row['pen'];
                $r4= $r2 - $r3; 
                $r5 =$r1 * 100;
                if($r4 == 0)
                    {
                        $r6 =0;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $r6 = $r5 / $r4;
                    }   
            }
           echo "<td>$r6</td></tr>";
    }
```

Thanks :)